# R Regular expression for csv data input

Tags: regex, r

Could you help me with command for data import of CSV file with subset in it?
So format is like this:

```
A, B, fragments[(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6)(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6)(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6)<etc..>], C, D, E
```

So problem is with fragment list. Notice that there are no comma between ()

EDIT:
IN:

```
 text1, text2, fragments[(atr1, atr2, atr3, atr4, atr5, atr6)(atr1, atr2, atr3, atr4, atr5, atr6)(atr1, atr2, atr3, atr4, atr5, atr6)], text3, text4, text5, text6 /n
```

OUT(inported in R global environment data):

```
 text1, text2, fr1_atr1, ..., fr1_atr6, fr2_atr1,..., frn_atr6, text3, text4, text5, text6 /n
```

Comment: What would be your expected output?  Also, provide an example that mimic your original data.

Comment: output should be R matrix type, or csv which should be easy to import in R. This raw above could mimic data, please see edit.

Comment: I don't find any edit.

Comment: Sorry..here it is...